# JsTree 3.3.12 disable nodes by node type

Tags: jstree

I have many types for my tree, and i want to disable all nodes with common type ('disabled'). Is this possible in jsTree 3.3.12? Older version of jsTree has options for that but they don't seem to work for me:

```
types : {
// the default type
"default" : {
    "max_children"  : -1,
    "max_depth"     : -1,
    "valid_children": "all"

    // Bound functions - you can bind any other function here (using boolean or function)
    //"select_node" : true,
    //"open_node"   : true,
    //"close_node"  : true,
    //"create_node" : true,
    //"delete_node" : true
}
```

If its not possible, how can i get all nodes by type so i can disable them in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

As I can edit incoming json data, I just added `{state: {disabled: true}}` to nodes with required type.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con lo siguiente:

```
var jsTreeId = document.getElementById('treeElement');
```

for a new node set:

```
jsTreeId.jstree(true).rename_node(node, node.text);
```

Comment: Please make sure the whole content of your answer is in English